# Array filter data in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, lodash

I have working array filter using javascript and lodash. I want to converts array of array into a single array. Anyone can you tell converts in single array.

**Input data**

```
const inputData = [
  [
    { 'Tempe(C)': 12 },
    { 'Tempe(C)': 13 },
    { 'Tempe(C)': 14 },
    { 'Tempe(C)': 15 }
  ],
  [
    { 'Tempe(C)': 22 },
    { 'Tempe(C)': 23 },
    { 'Tempe(C)': 24 },
    { 'Tempe(C)': 25 }
  ],
  [
    { 'Tempe(C)': 32 },
    { 'Tempe(C)': 33 },
    { 'Tempe(C)': 34 },
    { 'Tempe(C)': 35 }
  ],
];
```

**I want this structure of output**

```
const outputData = [
  [12, 13, 14, 15],
  [22, 23, 24, 25],
  [32, 33, 34, 35],      
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Tempe(C)` is always the key for the values, you can simply do:

```js
const inputData=[[{"Tempe(C)":12},{"Tempe(C)":13},{"Tempe(C)":14},{"Tempe(C)":15}],[{"Tempe(C)":22},{"Tempe(C)":23},{"Tempe(C)":24},{"Tempe(C)":25}],[{"Tempe(C)":32},{"Tempe(C)":33},{"Tempe(C)":34},{"Tempe(C)":35}]];

const output = inputData.map(arr => arr.map(data => data['Tempe(C)']));

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const inputData = [[{"Tempe(C)":12},{"Tempe(C)":13},{"Tempe(C)":14},{"Tempe(C)":15}],[{"Tempe(C)":22},{"Tempe(C)":23},{"Tempe(C)":24},{"Tempe(C)":25}],[{"Tempe(C)":32},{"Tempe(C)":33},{"Tempe(C)":34},{"Tempe(C)":35}]];
const output = inputData.map(arr => arr.map(a => Object.values(a)[0]))
console.log(output)
```

If [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is supported in your browser:

```js
const inputData = [[{"Tempe(C)":12},{"Tempe(C)":13},{"Tempe(C)":14},{"Tempe(C)":15}],[{"Tempe(C)":22},{"Tempe(C)":23},{"Tempe(C)":24},{"Tempe(C)":25}],[{"Tempe(C)":32},{"Tempe(C)":33},{"Tempe(C)":34},{"Tempe(C)":35}]]
const output = inputData.map(arr => arr.map(Object.values).flat())

console.log(output)
```

(This works for any key. If the key is always `Tempe(C)`, @eol's answer is a much better option)

Comment: i had faced this type of error : TypeError: arr.map(...).flat is not a function

.............this way is working well :
inputData.map(arr => arr.map(data => data['Tempe(C)']));

Comment: @ragu `flat` is not supported in your browser. Updated with another option

Comment: This way also working well :  inputData.map(arr => arr.map(a => Object.values(a)[0]))

Answer (score 0):

Hi Ragu here is how you can achieve the wanted result :

```js
var inputData = [
    [
      { 'Tempe(C)': 12 },
      { 'Tempe(C)': 13 },
      { 'Tempe(C)': 14 },
      { 'Tempe(C)': 15 }
    ],
    [
      { 'Tempe(C)': 22 },
      { 'Tempe(C)': 23 },
      { 'Tempe(C)': 24 },
      { 'Tempe(C)': 25 }
    ],
    [
      { 'Tempe(C)': 32 },
      { 'Tempe(C)': 33 },
      { 'Tempe(C)': 34 },
      { 'Tempe(C)': 35 }
    ],
  ];

var newstructure = [];

for(var i in inputData){
    newstructure[i] = [];
    for(var j in inputData[i]){
        newstructure[i][j] = inputData[i][j]["Tempe(C)"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With lodash you can use nested `_.map()` calls to get the result:

```js
const data = [[{"Tempe(C)":12},{"Tempe(C)":13},{"Tempe(C)":14},{"Tempe(C)":15}],[{"Tempe(C)":22},{"Tempe(C)":23},{"Tempe(C)":24},{"Tempe(C)":25}],[{"Tempe(C)":32},{"Tempe(C)":33},{"Tempe(C)":34},{"Tempe(C)":35}]]

const result =  _.map(data, o => _.map(o, 'Tempe(C)'))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the same idea using [lodash/fp](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide):

```js
const fn = _.map(_.map('Tempe(C)'))

const data = [[{"Tempe(C)":12},{"Tempe(C)":13},{"Tempe(C)":14},{"Tempe(C)":15}],[{"Tempe(C)":22},{"Tempe(C)":23},{"Tempe(C)":24},{"Tempe(C)":25}],[{"Tempe(C)":32},{"Tempe(C)":33},{"Tempe(C)":34},{"Tempe(C)":35}]]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```